# Update from subquery SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have tblPatient with the county name and state name in the table.  I have a look up table for both county name and state name and I'm trying to normalize my tblPatient, its structure is
[image]

As you can imagine, different states sometimes share county names.  To deal with this I'm using the query

```
select patientid, admissionDate, dischargeDate, patientState, patientCounty
from tblPatient
where patientState='AL'
```

I'd like to update `tblPatient.patientCounty` to equal `tblStateCounties.countyCode` where patientCounty and countyName are the same.

I haven't had a dummy's version of how to use `rollback` yet, but this looks correct to me, yet I don't want to be committed to a possibly silly error.

```
update tblPatient
set tblPatient.patientCounty=tblStateCountes.countyCode
from 
(
select patientID, admissionDate, dischargeDate, patientState, patientCounty from tblPatient
where patientState='AL'
) as t
inner join on tblStateCounties.countyName=tblPatient.countyName
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query you wrote won't parse (you can check that easily enough) because you're missing the FROM clause in your sub query.You'd also need to JOIN on `t.tblPatient` and also you'd need tblPatient in your main FROM clause.

You can use the query below to update your table.

```
UPDATE tblPatient 
SET    tblPatient.patientCounty = tblStateCounties.countyCode 
FROM   tblPatient 
       INNER JOIN tblStateCounties 
               ON tblStateCounties.countyName = tblPatient.patientCounty 
WHERE  patientState = 'AL' 
       AND tblStateCounties.stateCode = '01';
```

You'll notice I removed the subquery and used a simple where clause. Since you noted that counties can share names so you will need to filter for the tblStateCounties.stateCode as well

Also consider making a table mapping of StateNames to StateCode (if you don't have that already)

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce1cc/2)

Comment: I see why this will work now, joining on two columns instead of using a subquery.  I edited my original query to include the `from` statement.  How would the join look if I kept the subquery from my original query?

Comment: You still need tblPatient in the FROM since that that table you're updating. So it would  just be `ON tblPatient.PatientID = t.PatientID` [See here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce1cc/4)